# Is this a bug in my code or in g++'s analysis of -Weffc++?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, gcc-warning, effective-c++

I'm getting a warning thrown by -Weffc++ which appears to be wrong. I could use a second pair of eyes to confirm:

```
template<template<class> class CLASS_TYPE, typename T>
class some_class
{
typedef CLASS_TYPE<T> class_type;

public:
   virtual ~some_class() {};
   virtual class_type& operator++() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class other_class
:
public some_class<other_class, T>
{
public:
   virtual ~other_class() {};
   other_class<T>& operator++() {
      return *this;
   };
};

int main() {

   return 0;
}
```

The warning is:

```
main.cpp:8:39: warning: prefix ‘some_class<CLASS_TYPE, T>::class_type& some_class<CLASS_TYPE, T>::operator++()’ should return ‘some_class<CLASS_TYPE, T>&’ [-Weffc++]
    virtual class_type& operator++() = 0;
```

Tested with `g++ (GCC) 4.9.3`.

**UPDATE**

Added an additional class to provide an implementation example. The warning is *correct* pre se but I think my disagreement is for the warning to appear on a pure virtual function as it's meant to be an interface for another class.

@Frerich Raabe has provided the necessary clarification as to why g++ thinks I'm violating the rules set by Effective C++ and I've accepted this answer.

To silence the warning I have added the following:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Weffc++"
virtual class_type& operator++() = 0;
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Is `CLASS_TYPE<T>` the same type as `some_class<CLASS_TYPE, T>`?  I would expect `some_class<CLASS_TYPE, T>` to be returned.

Comment: You're asking for confirmation that the compiler reports that warning for that code? [Confirmed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bbd9555da6f5496). Do you have reason to believe the compiler is wrong? You haven't stated any.

Comment: Added additional clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is correct. Your `operator++` reimplementation should return a value of the same type as `*this`, i.e. a `some_class<...>`. In fact, many implementations of `operator++()` end in

```
return *this;
```

See the section labelled 'Unary arithmetic operators' in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/91757) for a more elaborate discussion.

Comment: You are correct but my disagreement is the warning appearing on a pure virtual function. I suppose you're right that the *warning* is valid; it is a warning and not an error.